# В каких случаях лучше использовать сессии а в какихи куки?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, http, cookie, сессия

Вопрос следующий. В чем состоят преимущества сессии над куками и наоборот?

На мой скромный дилетантский взгляд, механизм кукесов может справиться со всеми теми же задачами что и механизм сессий. И сессии нам могут понадобиться только в том случае если у пользователя отключены кукесы.
Так это или нет? И в каких случаях лучше использовать один механизм а в каких другой? И почему?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253633/cookies-vs-sessions

Comment: Спасибо вот то зачем я пришел - "Session is preferred when you need to store short-term information/values, such as variables for calculating, measuring, querying etc.

Cookies is preferred when you need to store long-term information/values, such as user's account (so that even when they shutdown the computer for 2 days, their account will still be logged in). I can't think of many examples for cookies since it isn't adopted in most of the situations."